# Files in 'C:/Users/Tomin Jacob' gone missing after uninstalling an application

Tags: windows-8, uninstall

Some minutes before I uninstalled Wise Folder from my Windows 8 system using IOBit Uninstaller. Am the admin of my system. The uninstallation took more time than usual, but I waited it to complete. After the uninstallation all files and folders in the 'C:/Users/Tomin Jacob' folder got missing, except the 'AppData' folder.

Before uninstallation I had a look at C:/Users/Tomin Jacob and there I found some files of Wise Folder Hider. I just wanted to remove those files from there, so I decided to uninstall it.

During installation, I chose C:/Users/Tomin Jacob/AppData/Local as the installation folder for Wise Folder Hider.

After this event I tried to make a System Restore, but got an error saying "no restore pints have been created on your computer system drive". Then I restarted my system and when came to metro screen no Windows apps(like News, Weather, Messaging, Mails, Bing) were there.

I want all that files in C:/Users/Tomin Jacob very badly. What to do ?

---

UPDATE :

The apps that were installed recently are not working now.

Comment: Did you unhide everything before uninstalling? Looks like IOBit thought all the hidden files belonged to Wise & deleted them too. Recovery software next... or you have a backup?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes I unhided files.

Comment: then I guess IOBit didn't understand that. Backup/recovery time, I'd say. One reason to not use uninstallers, they don't always fully understand install systems.

Comment: @Tetsujin What to do now ?

Comment: as above - "Recovery software next... or you have a backup?"

Comment: @Tetsujin Suggest a good recovery software ?

Comment: I would post that as a separate question in http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com [or at least search it first] I'm predominantly Mac, so my answer for windows would be straight from Google; better to get expert recommendations.